# Job running in server-side need to invoke a method which runs on client-side

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Suppose i have a job which runs in server-side and a line in the same job needs to run on client-side, Can this be achieved? When I try to run the method WeekofYear in Global class in batch, it is not executed (cause it makes calls to WINApi class methods which can only run on client.)

KIndly Assist.

Comment: I have no problem running `weekofYear` from server. Please clarify the problem you're having.

Comment: WeekofYear when i run in batch i get the error "The server side impersonated(RunAs) session tried to invoke a method available for client-side processing only"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only suggest you to create a new method e.g. `Global::weekOfYearServer` and make sure all the WinAPI calls are executed on server - you can try creating appropriate methods in the `WinAPIServer` class.

Comment: is it feasible to put runsImpersonated() method in RunBaseBatch to false. I tried doing that, it works. But I dont Think its a good idea to tempar with the framework classes as Skaue suggested.

Comment: You can do that but of course you should not modify `RunBaseBatch.runsImpersonated` but rather create a new method in your class: `public boolean runsImpersonated() { return false; }` - it'll instruct the batch framework to run this class on a client.

Comment: thanks alot 10p. What i did is in my class BatchJobTry(extends RunBaseBatch) i overrided the method runsImpersonated() and removed the call to super, returned false and it executed flawlessly. So what i conclude is it depends on my needs to manipulate(whether to run Client-side or Server-side) the methods and make sure that the whole job runs fully either on Client-side or Server-side or both. Thanks a lot again.(correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: im glad that im correct. thanks for the reference. happy coding.

Comment: You can use the buildin `wkofyr()` function, but only if you agree that the first week is the week with the first Thursday!